# from ipynb to py with jupiter lab export

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I open Jupyter lab,
I go to

1. file
2. Export Notebook As
3. Export Notebook As Executable Script.

I than get a warning from my system saying:
This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep filename.py anyway?

Is there risk involved? Why do I get the warning? Would you recommend that way to convert my .ipynb to .py?

Answer (score 0):

You are warned because your browser noticed that you are trying to download some `.py` script. When you download some from the Internet it really can be harmful. But the browser doesn't know that actually, it's your own code. So download it, you'll be fine.